# Update array em subdocumento MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

estou tentando fazer um update aqui no mongoshell e estou com dificuldades.

Possuo o seguinte json:

```
{

"_id" : ObjectId("56cc03c16f4e85f538ef79ae"),
"contact_id" : NumberLong(1000295524418),
"gender" : 1,
"phonetic_gender" : 1,
"first_name" : "LEANDRO",
"score" : 44,
"address" : [ 
    {
        "address_id" : NumberLong(2634224807),
        "rank" : 201604.0,
        "score" : 7.0,
        "street_type" : "AV",
        "street_title" : "DA",
        "street" : "EMILIA DE CASTRO MARTINS",
        "number" : 34.0,
        "district" : "JARDIM BELA VISTA",
        "city" : "GUARULHOS",
        "state" : "SP",
        "zip_code" : 7132470.0,
        "create_date" : ISODate("2014-08-07T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "update_date" : ISODate("2016-05-03T00:00:00.000Z")
    }, 
    {
        "address_id" : NumberLong(2634735566),
        "rank" : 201410,
        "score" : 10,
        "street_type" : "AV",
        "street_title" : "DA",
        "street" : "EMILIA DE CASTRO MARTINS",
        "district" : "JARDIM BELA VISTA",
        "city" : "GUARULHOS",
        "state" : "SP",
        "zip_code" : "07132470",
        "create_date" : ISODate("2014-08-07T03:00:00.000Z"),
        "update_date" : ISODate("2014-08-07T03:00:00.000Z")
    }
]}
```

Preciso percorrer todos os meus documentos e atualizar o tipo do campo rank e score no array de address.

Veja o seguinte código que estou fazendo:

```
var total = 0
var skip = 0
var total_adress = db.company.count() - skip
var bulk = db.person.initializeUnorderedBulkOp()
var person = db.getCollection('Person').find( {$and:[ {"contact_id":1000295524418}).addOption(DBQuery.Option.noTimeout).forEach(
function(person){
        var contact_id = person.contact_id.valueOf()
            bulk.find(
                { contact_id: contact_id  }
            ).update(
                { 
                    $set: {
                        "address.$.zip_code":"address.zip_code".toString(),
                        "address.$.rank": NumberInt("address.rank"),
                        "address.$.number": "address.number".toString(),
                        "address.$.score": NumberInt("address.score") - 2
                    }
                } 
            );


    if((++total % 1000) === 0){
        print("Total person....: " + total_adress)
        print("Iniciando bulk..: " + Date())
        bulk.execute({ w: 0 })
        bulk = db.company.initializeUnorderedBulkOp()
        print("Fim bulk........: " + Date())
        print("#############################################################################")
    }
}); bulk.execute();  print(total);
```

Agora vem o problema, quando executo este comando no Mongo o mesmo não dá erro. Já me certifiquei que ele cai dentro do foreach e e busca o meu dado no campo corretamente, o problema é só o update que não funciona.

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Eu ainda não usei `Bulk` mas em updates normais, tipo `db.mycollection.update(query, updates, {multi: true})` você só pode utilizar o `$` quando o predicado (`query`) se refere a algum atributo dentro do array. Outra coisa é que você não pode se referir a outros atributos do mesmo documento *por nome* como você tentou em `"address.zip_code".toString()`.

Acredito que você precise de algo mais manual, tipo:

```
function(person){
    var contact_id = person.contact_id.valueOf(),
        updates = { $set: {}};
        person.address.forEach(function(addr, i){
            updates.$set['address.' + i + '.zip_code'] = addr.zip_code.toString();
            updates.$set['address.' + i + '.rank'] = NumberInt(addr.rank);
            updates.$set['address.' + i + '.number'] = addr.number ? addr.number.toString() : null;
            updates.$set['address.' + i + '.score'] = NumberInt(addr.score);
        });

        bulk.find({ contact_id: contact_id  }).update(updates);

    // ...
}
```